# DispatcherTimer not firing Tick event

Tags: c#, dispatchertimer

I have a DispatcherTimer i have initialised like so:

```
static DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

static void Main()
{
    _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
    _timer.Start();
}
static void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

The _timer_Tick event never gets fired, have i missed something?

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx your code looks good.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If this is your main entry point, it's likely (near certain) that the `Main` method exits prior to when the first `DispatcherTimer` event could ever occur.

As soon as Main finishes, the process will shut down, as there are no other foreground threads.

That being said, `DispatcherTimer` really only makes sense in a use case where you have a `Dispatcher`, such as a WPF or Silverlight application.  For a console mode application, you should consider using the [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), ie:

```
static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

static void Main()
{
    _timer.Interval = 5000;
    _timer.Elapsed  += _timer_Tick;
    _timer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey(); // Block until you hit a key to prevent shutdown
}
static void _timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer Elapsed!");
}
```

Comment: the program does other stuff, this is just the code related to the DispatcherTimer.

Comment: @harryovers: That's fine - is it a console application?  If so, DispatcherTimer is inappropriate, since there will be no dispatcher running...

Comment: This is also not working. So what to do if I just want to use a timer in Console application without too much of code?

Comment: @Tanmoy Use a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`

Answer (score 6):

because the main method thread ended before the tick was called.

Comment: + 1 Good catch, I totally missed that in my reading of things

Answer (score 5):

You missed Application.Run().  Tick events cannot be dispatched without the dispatcher loop.  A secondary issue is that your program immediately terminates before the event ever could be raised.  Application.Run() solves that too, it blocks the Main() method.

Answer (score 4):

If the timer is created in a worker thread, the `Tick` event will not fire because there is not dispatcher.

You have to create the timer in the UI thread or use the `DispatcherTimer` constructor which takes a `Dispatcher` instance as the second argument, passing the UI dispatcher:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background, uiDispatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start a dispatcher in order for the dispatcher to "do" any events. If you are running inside of a WPF application, this should happen automatically. If you are running in a console (which it looks like), this will never fire because there isn't a dispatcher. The easiest thing you can do is try this in a WPF application and it should work fine.

Answer (score -3):

You have to use

```
static void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{

}
```

in the place of timer_tick event

Comment: not true, `_timer.Elapsed  += _timer_Tick;` sets what method to call once the timer has elapsed